# Reject the Input based on the Percentage

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried playing around the script but it didn't work as I expected (which works on Google Webapp script HTML form), I want to reject the input if the **Downpayment** is **lesser than 30%** or **more than 100%** of the **Price**, the answer should be **Invalid Input**. What should be changed in this script?

```
//------------------------Process---------------------------------------//
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  const rate = 0.155;
  
  const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
  const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
  const period = document.getElementById("app").value;
  
  var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(); //number format 
  const res =  nf.format(Math.round ((vprice - downPayment) * rate / period));
  
  
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Your Estimated Monthly Rental: "+ res;
  google.script.run.userClicked({
    vprice,
    downPayment,
    rate,
    period,
    res
  });
}
```

Comment: Put that line after you define downPayment: `if(downPayment<0.3 || downPayment>1) {document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Invalid Input"; return ; )`

Comment: @Marios I added your line after const downPayment variable, as I refresh the form, the period dropdown box is disappearing. did I do anything wrong?

Comment: What does `userClicked` does ?

Comment: @Marios Nothing

Comment: Can you share a copy of the file please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222220/discussion-between-muhammed-aadhil-and-marios).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
  <script>
  

  //dropdown for html----------------
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });
  //---------------------------------
  
  
  
  //------------------------Process---------------------------------------//
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

    function doStuff() {
      const rate = 0.155;
      
      const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
      const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
      const period = document.getElementById("app").value;
      var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(); //number format 
      const res =  nf.format(Math.round ((vprice - downPayment) * rate / period));

      
      if(parseInt(downPayment) < 0.3*parseInt(vprice) || parseInt(downPayment) > parseInt(vprice)) {
      
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Invalid Input";
      
      }
      
      else {
      
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Your Estimated Monthly Rental: "+ res;
      google.script.run.userClicked({
        vprice,
        downPayment,
        rate,
        period,
        res
      });
      
      }
     
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem, the dropdown box doesn't appear in my HTML form after adding that line. :(